# Achieving High TPS with less connection using LR

Tags: performance, ibm-mq, performance-testing, loadrunner

Is there any way to achieve high tps making minimal connections using LoadRunner.
I am using Java protocol to test MQ.

Current scenario could achieve 30 TPS putting load of 15 Vusers.
Is there any way to use 2,3 Vusers and achieve 30 TPS?

My scenario looks like this,

1. init()-- Make connection to Qmgr
2. Action()-- sending message and getting the response
3. End()--- closing the connection.

Comment: How many connections are used in production?  I do not understand your desire to reduce connections, please clarify the technical nature of the need.

Comment: Actually the Queues are shared and we are asked to use minimal connections. Is it even possible ?  if yes pls guide a little.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions that should have a definitive answer. This question asks for performance tuning approaches but fails to provide any detail. It *might* be appropriate if it mentioned a lot more detail about the config, tuning and diagnostics. Voting to hold.  Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). See also IBM's [Performance Reports](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg27007150&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en).

Answer (score 0):

So you're saying currently for each virtual user you can only achieve 2TPS.

If you have more than one iteration defined in your run time settings, then the 'Action' should be looping and reusing the current connection. If you're already doing this then that is as fast as you can go with a single thread.
Ensure the script is correctly re-using the connection within Action().

Otherwise the only way to speed things up is to optimise the code of the script.

Ensure that the messages aren't consumed too fast, I've found that trying to read off an empty IBM MQ can cause vusers to stall.